# Chrome Extensions page Errors display seems to contain bogus errors

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I am using the latest Canary build (Version 57.0.2953.0 32-bit).  The Extensions page shows errors for my very simple extension as follows:

[image]

When I click on the Errors link, the following is displayed:

[image]

However, there is no actual problem with the script. It prints to the console as expected, and receives and reacts to event notifications.

If I click on the "Clear all" link (top right corner), the errors are cleared, the "Errors" link goes away, and upon a Reload, the errors are no longer displayed.

Should I consider this a bug in Canary?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. If this is not a global bug in Canary, we will need a [mcve] that duplicates the problem to be able to evaluate if this is a bug in Canary, and, if so, what the parameters of the bug are (under what conditions it occurs).

Comment: @Makyen Thank you, no problem re: chat.  I will collect the extension files necessary to repro the problem.

Comment: BTW: Something that you could do for this is see if using a completely different extension, which has very simple code, produces the same issue (don't reuse any of your current code; pick a known working extension which does not show this issue on Chrome release). If it does show the issue on Canary, then this is almost certainly a Canary bug, if not, then it at least has *something* to do with your code. It would then be necessary to work down to find the conditions which cause the issue.

Comment: @Makyen Good advice, thank you.

Comment: @Makyen You were right, I checked and this problem definitely does not happen in the release version of Chrome.  Please re-post your comment as an answer so I can accept it.  Thanks.